# Adding key vault to my app causes start up error when published (works locally)

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-keyvault

My web app runs into a startup error 500.30 whenever I add the Azure key vault app configuration to my program.cs file. Locally I have access to the vault and have tested it but once published I receive the error.

I've tried adding both System and User identities to my web app and granting it permission through both Azure access control and access policies. I've given the app access to the entire resource as well. I've commented out this portion and the app runs which is why I've attributed the error to the key vault.

```cs
public static IWebHost CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
           WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)

// this gets commented out to run properly
               .ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, builder) =>
               {
                   var keyVaultEndpoint = GetKeyVaultEndpoint();
                   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultEndpoint))
                   {
                       var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                       var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
                           new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                               azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
                       builder.AddAzureKeyVault(
                           keyVaultEndpoint, keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
                   }


               }
               ) // until here 
               .UseStartup<Startup>()
               .Build();

private static string GetKeyVaultEndpoint() => "https://<vault name>.vault.azure.net/";
```

I expect to be able to access the key vault. the app throws HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure when published.

Update:
After changing to OutOfProcess I now get error 502.5. with the following message:

```
Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProviderException: Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/<MyId>. Exception Message: Tried the following 3 methods to get an access token, but none of them worked.
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/<MyId>. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. Access token could not be acquired. Failed after 5 retries. MSI ResponseCode: BadRequest, Response: 
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/<MyID>. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Visual Studio. Access token could not be acquired. Visual Studio Token provider file not found at "D:\local\LocalAppData\.IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth\tokenprovider.json"
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/<MyId>. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Azure CLI. Access token could not be acquired. 'az' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Have you tried enabling stdout logs and seeing what the error is?

Comment: I've tried enabling them but the logs come out empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the same issue and i got the same error, to resolve the issue try following:

Open your*.csproj file ,find the **`Property group tag`**  and update it to:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>       
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <AspNetCoreModuleName>AspNetCoreModule</AspNetCoreModuleName>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Try and see if it helps.

Comment: This changed my error to 502.25 but didn't resolve the issue. I now can check the stdout log and will update the question.

Comment: After more poking around I changed my app to be system assigned Identity and I think in combination with this it works now so I'm marking this as the answer.